# Clearing Map Polylines using a Loop

Tags: leaflet, mobile, angularjs

My problem is, I tried this solution in order to clear the polylines on the map. Here's some code for your reference:

```
var line;
 $scope.clearPolylines = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i ++){ // coordinates is an array
        map.removeLayer(line._latlngs[i]);
        console.log("[ DELETE LINES ]", line._latlngs[i]);
    }
}
```

But it is not clearing on the map. Are there other ways possible?

This solution is based on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585688/clear-all-polylines-from-leaflet-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to GIS SE,

Not exactly sure how you came up with that code based on the posts you refer to?

Anyway, the essence is to **record** the references to your polylines in a temporary variable / array / whatever, when you first add them to your map.

Then later on you can loop through that temporary variable / array and remove them from the map.

The posts you refer to try to directly read the layers currently added to the map, you could achieve something very similar by using [`map.eachLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-eachlayer) method. Then they check the `_path` property to differentiate between any layer and those which are actually polylines.

An interesting comment is about using an intermediate layer: instead of adding your polylines directly to the map, add them to an [`L.layerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup). Of course you add that group to the map so that it displays your polylines. But later on, you just need to remove that group from the map, to hide all its child polylines.

NB: for very programming related questions like this, you might reach a more suitable audience directly on Stack Overflow.